# Synchronize progress indicator with function called on an interval using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a few Ajax calls that I make to update some page elements. These calls are made on a 10-second interval. I want to show a progress bar that progresses towards the 10-second interval. This will allow users to see that the page data is being refreshed. Here is my code:

```
var _interval = setInterval(updateProgress, 1000);
var _width = 0;

// update the page data ever 10 seconds
setInterval( function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/get_sensor_data",
    }).done( function( data ) {
        var h = data[0]['bitrate'];
        $( "#ops_status_bitrate h1" ).text( h );
    }).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown );
    });
}, 10000 );


// update the progress indicator
function updateProgress() {

    if (_width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(_interval);
        _width = 0;
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', _width+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', _width);
        _interval = setInterval(updateProgress, 1000);

    } else {
        _width+=10;
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', _width+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', _width);
    }

}
```

The problem is that the progress indicator is disconnected from the Ajax call. It works for the initial 10 seconds then it starts to fall behind. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Apart from lagging behind, does your progress bar work?

Comment: Yes, it works fine otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go would be to just use 1 interval:

```
function updateProgress() {
  if (!this.count) this.count = 0 else this.count = (this.count + 1) % 10;
  if (this.count === 0) // do your ajax call
    if (_width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(_interval);
        _width = 0;
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', _width+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', _width);
        _interval = setInterval(updateProgress, 1000);

    } else {
        _width+=10;
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', _width+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', _width);
    }

}
```

Another way would be to reset/restart the graphics interval

```
setInterval( function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/get_sensor_data",
    }).done( function( data ) {
        var h = data[0]['bitrate'];
        $( "#ops_status_bitrate h1" ).text( h );
    }).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown );
    });
    _interval.clear();
    _interval = setInterval(updateProgress, 1000);
}, 10000 );
```